# How to get html tags content

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to get tags content in a string with regular expression. I wrote it for just one line. When the content changed into some lines from one line, Regex will never do pattern on the tag. I choose `RegexOptions.Multiline + RegexOptions.Singleline` for finding options.

My pattern in low level: `(>)[ a-z A-z 0-9 ]*(</)`

Thanks.

Comment: obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: it was complete but not for my job.

Answer (score 2):

It's not cool parsing HTML with Regular Expressions. There's a .NET code library called [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for that.

Comment: It's cool but my aim is so different. I'm now writing a syntax highlighter which using regex is a necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the nodeValue attribute?
that should let you get the content from a div tag.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml